# Turtle Graphics displaying pixelated graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I created a random spot painting generator program as part of the course that I'm following.
My code involves using the `turtle.dot()` function to create dots anywhere the turtle goes.
The actual logic seems to work fine but it's creating pixelated dots, as in, blurred images.

The course videos have perfect outputs - exactly how circles should be.

I switched from VSCode to PyCharm but that didn't help. I also created a bunch of other Turtle Graphics programs - Spirograph generators, Random walk and none of them produce sharp objects on screen, as you'd expect from a 21st century machine.

I cannot figure out what the issue is. Is it the code? display drivers? or some bug?

Here's the code:

```py
import turtle
turtle.colormode(255)

t = turtle.Turtle()
s = turtle.Screen()
t.penup()
t.speed(0)
t.setpos(-200, -200)

for m in range(10):
    for n in range(10):
        t.dot(20, 'red')
        t.forward(50)
    t.setx(-200)
    t.sety(t.ycor()+50)

s.exitonclick()
```

Notice how the spots look like polygons and not, circles:

[image: Notice how the spots look like polygons and not, circles.]

Comment: Hi Prabhav. Can you please post your code, so that people who want to help you can easily run your code and try to reproduce your issue? Thanks!

Comment: I've added the relevant code to my question now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you should be using something other than python turtle if you want RTX level graphics. That's just how turtle is, it was made to be like the first robot ever invented. named a turtle. http://cyberneticzoo.com/cyberneticanimals/1969-the-logo-turtle-seymour-papert-marvin-minsky-et-al-american/

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could try though is turtle.shape() and turtle.stamp()
like this:

```
import turtle
turtle.colormode(255)

t = turtle.Turtle()
s = turtle.Screen()
t.penup()
t.speed(0)
t.setpos(-200, -200)

for m in range(10):
    for n in range(10):
        t.shape("circle")
        t.stamp()
        t.forward(50)
    t.setx(-200)
    t.sety(t.ycor()+50)


s.exitonclick()
```

Its not perfect but you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You may be blaming your *code* when the problem is actually your *environment*.  Your `dot()`-based code generates great circles on my system:

[image]

And if we take a closer look, they are nicely anti-alised:

[image]

You teacher may just have a better graphics subsystem and/or display.  We can try turtle's `circle()` method:

```
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(10)
turtle.end_fill()
```

But that doesn't look better than `dot()`:

[image]

Which the closeup confirms:

[image]

But `circle()` doesn't try very hard with small radii, which we can override using the `steps` argument:

```
turtle.circle(10, steps=180)
```

[image]

And again in closeup:

[image]

@RobertMcNeil's `stamp()` suggestion produces even worse results on my system:

[image]

Along with a final closeup:

[image]

I'd say stick with your original design and test it on different systems.

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import random

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(-200, -200)

for _ in range(10):
    for _ in range(10):
        turtle.dot(20, (random(), random(), random()))
        turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.setx(-200)
    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() + 50)

screen.exitonclick()
```